# iPhone Scrollview question?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, uiscrollview, scrollbar

Is there a way to hide the scroll bar in a scroll view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];    
[scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
```

This is [in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/showsHorizontalScrollIndicator).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in interface builder also, by unchecking the the scrollers horizontal and vertical property.